# React PDF Display issue with Bundle.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' and url not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle, react-pdf

I am trying to display a pdf on my web page using the react-pdf library, however whenever I try to load the page I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:187976:58)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:187995:7
```

And I don't really know what this means and all of my other pages work other then this one, here is my code if anyone can help:

```
import React from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";

const ResumeDisplay = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Document
        file={
          "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
        }
      >
        <Page pageNumber={1} />
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResumeDisplay;
```

Comment: Are you sure all your react-javascript files have `.jsx` extension as opposed to `.js`?

Comment: The most obvious reason would be that you haven't configured your development environment correctly, and JSX is not converted into standard JavaScript. You can easily test if this is the case by simply returning `<h1>Hello World!</h1>` from your `ResumeDisplay` component. If you still get the error, it's not react-pdf related. If the error is gone, I would check the response you get from the provided PDF URL. Open your browser web-developer tools, go to "Network" and check if the PDF response is successful, also check the "JavaScript" tab for any errors. Do you see anything unusual?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I can load other things such as the h1 you mentioned. I checked the Network and do see I get a 304 not modified from bundle.js and bundle.worker.js when I go to the resume page. It does respond with Failed to load PDF file in my div when I remove the error screen from react

Comment: @spender all my files and pages in my project have the js extension and have all been working

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `<` with `&lt;`.

Comment: Where would I change this?

Answer (score 0):

FIX:
I imported pdfjs and needed to use useEffect for the url as React thought it was rendering multiple times:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";
import { pdfjs } from "react-pdf";

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js",
  import.meta.url
).toString();

const ResumeDisplay = () => {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(1);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  const onFileChange = (url) => {
    setFile(url);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onFileChange(
      "https://mypdf.pdf"
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {file && (
        <Document file={file} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
      )}
      <p>
        Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResumeDisplay;
```